# Node.js, OpenCV Trying to convert matrix to buffer with toBuffer() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I'm trying to convert openCv matrix using `toBuffer()`, it works fine with matrix that I create via `var mat = new cv.Matrix()`, but when I do the same with image opened via `cv.readImage`, toBuffer() returns nothing, here is my code:

```
var cv =require('opencv');
var output;
var mat = new cv.Matrix(90,90);
cv.readImage("mona0.png", function(err,im){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

  im.bilateralFilter();
  console.log(im);
  output = im.clone();
  });
var buff = mat.toBuffer();// it works and returns something like <buffer ff d8 ff...>
//var buff = output.toBuffer(); // it doesn't work and returns nothing
console.log(buff);
```

So, if it's possible, I would like to get output from `im` similar to output from `mat`

Thank you in advance.

---

I tried the code you suggested, and it seems like after calling `.toBuffer` function it stops working, because resoult of `console.log('mat'+buff1)` doesn't show up [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6umW.png), so I found the way to convert something into the Buffer object (code is below), but in this way it converts the string '[Matrix 756*500]' not the contents of matrix, there is another tip which might be useful, if I'm trying to do  `var buff = new Buffer(output);`without converting to string it says, that `output` must be a string or array, so now I'm trying to convert `output` into array and there is a one more thing:  .toBufferAsync(), but it requires one argument, and I'm a bit confused which one.

```
 var cv =require('opencv');
var fs = require('fs');
var mat = new cv.Matrix(90,90);
cv.readImage("mona0.png", function(err,im){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

  im.bilateralFilter();
  console.log(im);
  var output = new cv.Matrix(im.width(),im.height())
  output = im.clone();
  var buff = new Buffer(output.toString('byte64')); // it should work now
  console.log('this is buff: ');
  console.log(buff);
  });
var buff1 = new Buffer(mat.toString('byte64'));// it works and returns something like <buffer ff d8 ff...>
console.log('this is buff1: ')
console.log(buff1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `cv.readImage()` is an asych process.

`output.toBuffer()` would have been evaluated before `cv.readImage` finishes reading the image.

try moving the `var buff = output.toBuffer();`  and see if you can see an out put... ie:

```
var cv =require('opencv');
var output;
var mat = new cv.Matrix(90,90);
cv.readImage("mona0.png", function(err,im){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

  im.bilateralFilter();
  console.log(im);
  output = im.clone();
  var buff = output.toBuffer(); // it should work now
  console.log('output'+buff)
  });
var buff1 = mat.toBuffer();// it works and returns something like <buffer ff d8 ff...>
console.log('mat'+buff1)
```

incidentally, log should display:

> mat BUFF1
>
> output BUFF

as a result of the async nature.

Edit: minor correction